# Importing entire phpmyadmin database into fresh system

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just formatted my windows system, Before that, I exported entire phpmyadmin database. It is named as 127_0_0_1.sql .Now when I have reinstalled the app and trying to import the file its not working. I tried to increase the size of the importable database from the .ini file. What should I do?

Comment: Why is it not working? Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied filed from xampp/mysql/data to new xampp/mysql/data and it worked!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use commandline to import your file :

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p -D your_database < 127_0_0_1.sql
```